# How to create ofstream file with the name of (integer type) variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, ofstream

```
int a
cin>>a;
ofstream file;
file.open("a.txt");
```

I want to create a .txt file with the code entered by the user. Please help.

Comment: If the user enters `23`, do you want to open `23.txt`?

Comment: yes If the user enters 23, i want to open 23.txt

Comment: Behold: [`to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: Why not simply read the input as a string instead? Why does it need to be read in as an integer? `string name; cin >> name; file.open(name+”.txt”);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to convert the input to `std::string`:

```
 int a;
 cin>>a;
 ofstream file(std::to_string(a) + ".txt");
```